# Importing '@react-three/drei' causes 'Invalid hook call.' immedietly followed by 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am using a simple drei `<Html>` component, and the issue occurs when importing any and all drei components, which makes me think it's not being caused by the way I'm using it.

I'm importing drei like so:

```
import { Html } from '@react-three/drei';
```

And using it (nested inside a larger component that is too bulky to post just for context):

```
<Html distanceFactor={10}>
    <div>
      hello <br />
      world
    </div>
</Html>
```

To test I also tried to import and use `<Box>` which triggered the same errors.

The full error in chrome dev tools:

[image]

In my attempts to solve this I can rule out breaking the rules of hooks as I am importing from a well known and well used project (drei), and from what I've read the mismatched versions thing is about older versions not supporting hooks, I'm on 18.2.

`npm ls react` got me:

[image]

I am fairly new to react and I assume i've just messed up my project settings somewhere, but I can't for the life of me track it down. I understand that I'm supposed to only have one copy of react per app but the result of that command seems to say every project I imported has it's own copy? Or are those peer dependencies?

I'd appreciate any help. Also as a side-note, I'm using typescript so perhaps that could be causing an issue?